# How to get email / SMS notifications for tweets for a specific user that match certain words?

Tags: twitter, twitter-integration

I know that Twitter already allow mobile notifications for new tweets from a specific user, but how can I go further and only get SMS (or email) notifications for new tweets from a specific that also match certain words? I know IFTTT doesn't do this, but are there any other ways I can use to do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**IFTTT** just announced new triggers for the [Twitter channel](https://ifttt.com/twitter), including "New tweet by a specific user" and "New tweet from search". The latter seems like it would do what you want.

The ingredients for the trigger are:

- Text
- FirstLinkUrl
- UserName
- UserImageUrl
- LinkToTweet
- TweetEmbedCode
- CreatedAt

Using [Twitter Advanced Search Operators](https://support.twitter.com/articles/71577-how-to-use-advanced-twitter-search) you can get what you need.

As an example, here's [a recipe that sends email when Wil Wheaton uses the hashtag "#butts"](https://ifttt.com/recipes/212564-email-me-when-wil-wheaton-tweets-about-butts).