# Twitter: Alert me only based on keywords in tweets?

Tags: twitter, keyword

Is there a way to only be alerted when keywords you've chosen are in the tweet of the person you are following?

Comment: This might be helpful: [How to get email / SMS notifications for tweets for a specific user that match certain words?](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/69046/354)

Comment: You can use https://mentions.xyz/ to create alerts for arbitrary search queries on Twitter. That might help you with your question.

Answer (score 0):

Twitter does not natively offer this functionality. You may be able to find it in a browser add-on or a mobile app. For add-on/app suggestions, try the [Software Recommendations](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/) Stack Exchange site.